# QTextEdit "pre-allocate" canvas size

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I'm writing a simple text editor client that receives a given file in chunks, instead of reading it all in at once. For example, if I have a 10,000 line file, I'll only get the first 25 lines + some slop when I open it up in the client. As I scroll down the file, it'll load the lines that come into view dynamically.

I've got the dynamic insertion of the file contents working as I scroll around the file. However, I want the QScrollBar to reflect the full size of the file when a file is opened, instead of just the current contents of the QTextDocument.

Here it is in screenshot form:

The QTextEdit and QScrollBar when a file is initially loaded with just the first chunk of lines.

[image]

The same thing, once I've scrolled to the bottom of the file and the rest of it has been loaded.

[image]

Note the smaller `QScrollBar` slider.

I'm wondering if there's some kind of way to preset the size of the underlying canvas, i.e. it would be easy to calculate the height of the full document in pixels, and then make the QTextEdit scroll area that size. Preferably without having to resort to painting. Any other ideas are also welcome.

Comment: Can't you dynamically pad the content to be displayed with blank lines in order to have same number of lines as the file?

Comment: @coolparadox I've thought of doing that, but then I'd be caching a lots of empty lines in the worst case. It could be optimized, but the point is to have the backend handle the actual file and only deal with the chunks that are currently visible.

Comment: Do you need `QTextEdit`? If it's a file without formatting, it's the wrong tool for the job. You could write one yourself instead.

Comment: It's eventually supposed to be a text editor, so QTextEdit has lots of nice features to that end. I am considering just painting on a QScrollArea at this point though...

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with programmatically setting the range of the vertical scrollbar:

```
textEdit->verticalScrollBar()->setMaximum(numberOfLines);
```

See the documentation for more details: [`QAbstractSlider::setMaximum()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#maximum-prop)

In addition, you will probably need to implement custom behavior when the `QAbstractSlider::sliderMoved(int)` signal is emitted. The idea is that your canvas stays small, it only provides a small window on the complete text.

Comment: Yes, I've played around with the code and realized that it's best to use QScollBar::setMaximum() to resize the canvas to the appropriate size. The problem is that using QTextDocument::insertText() resets the modification. Calling setMaximum() after each insertText() produces undesirable UX. I'll keep looking into this.